# solve equations with complex numbers using SymPy

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I want to solve set of equations with complex number with python sympy.  This equations are adds and multiply and divide complex numbers with  some of them conjugates. I've tried a test with `nonlinsolve` an a simple case, but I don't understand the solution. >>Here is the code:

```
a = 4 + 3j
b = 1 + 2j
x=a.conjugate() * b
y = a+b
# define the simbols and calculate a and b  with sympy nonlinsolve
a = Symbol('a', complex=True)
b = Symbol('b', complex=True)
ans = nonlinsolve([ x-conjugate(a) * b , y-(a+b) ], [a,b])
print(ans)
```

I was expecting results for a and b symbols, but i got this???:

FiniteSet((Complement({a}, ConditionSet(a, Eq(conjugate(a), 0), Complexes)), (10.0 + 5.0*I)/conjugate(a)))

so, what is this answer and is there a better or alternative method to perform this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for a better form, I replaced `j` with `*I` and expanded the real and imaginary parts of the expanded form of the expressions and let it solve for all variables. I get the following:

```py
a = 4 + 3*I
b = 1 + 2*I
x=a.conjugate() * b
y = a+b
# define the simbols and calculate a and b  with sympy nonlinsolve
a = Symbol('a', complex=True)
b = Symbol('b', complex=True)
eqs =[j for i in [x-conjugate(a) * b , y-(a+b) ]
      for j in i.expand(complex=True).as_real_imag()]
ans = solve(eqs)
print(ans)

# [{
a: 2 + I, 
b: 3 + 4*I, 
re(a): 2, re(b): 3, 
im(a): 1, im(b): 4}, 
{
a: 4 + 3*I, 
b: 1 + 2*I, 
re(a): 4, 
re(b): 1, 
im(a): 3, 
im(b): 2}]
```

Or with `nonlinsolve`:

```py
nonlinsolve(eqs, (re(a), im(a), re(b), im(b)))
# {(2, 1, 3, 4), (4, 3, 1, 2)}
```

Comment: thanks, but with nonlinsolve is possible?

Comment: thanks, but with 3 complex symbols on 3 equations solve and nonlinsolve:  hangs on time calculation. Is there a way to put a time limit so the result in an approximation ?

Comment: Try use `nsolve` (which will require an initial guess).